# Is it possible to store all files of joomla3 component in one folder inside installed joomla?

Tags: php, git, joomla

It's very comfort to develop module inside installed joomla because I have git repository. After each manipulation I could instantly check it then commit.

With components it is a little bit harder. Components is divided by site and admin parts.

Is it possible to store component completely in one directory?

Comment: In drupal you have no backend everything can be done at frontend. In Joomla it is not so as both are separate. You have to commit separately.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible on Joomla 3.X, since you have :

- Backend

  - Admin component
  - Admin language files
- Site

  - Site component
  - Site language files

**What you can do is using a script of some sort to make the job.**

Have a look at big Joomla open sources packages and see how they do that.

For example: easySDI does this with ANT: https://forge.easysdi.org/projects/easysdi/repository/show/branches/4.4.x/joomla
(look build.xml files at the root, and in the components)

Steps are:

1) You checkout their folder in the joomla install[1], and ANT will build the installer. Then you install the package.

2) Do some modifications on the code (IN PLACE in the Joomla install)

3) Run the *sync* on  *sync-package* ANT target, and the script will copy all the files from the different locations, and package the new installer.

4) You can then commit the changes.

Note [1] checkout must be in the root folder of joomla:

```
{Joomla root}
  adminstrator
  bin
  cache
  ...
  easysdi << here
  ...
  templates
  tmp
```

This option takes a little time at start (make your scripts), but is very comfortable afterwards